# Whats happening in the code which makes the dropdown button not follow the same formatting as the other buttons?

Tags: html, css

Whats happening in the code which makes the drop down button not follow the same formatting as the other buttons? I've tried making my own drop down button but my attempts have failed and even when I try to copy the drop downs it doesn't work as intended. I understand that my code is probably horrible and wrong but help is appreciated.

CSS:

```
.navbut
{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 15%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.navbut:hover
{
    background-color: black;
}


.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;

    /****************
     ** NEW STYLES **
     ****************/

    list-style: none; /** Remove list bullets */
    width: 100%; /** Set the width to 100% of it's parent */
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

    /** Button Styles **/
    .dropdown button {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 15%;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

/** List Item Styles **/
.dropdown a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
}

/** List Item Hover Styles **/
.dropdown a:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">

<button class="navbut">Home</button>
<button class="navbut">Prize draws</button>
<button class="navbut">Filler</button>
<button class="navbut">Filler</button>

<div class="dropdown">

    <!-- trigger button -->
    <button class="navbut">Navigate</button>

    <!-- dropdown menu -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The PHP tag should be replaced with CSS tag -- this has nothing to do with PHP.  For your CSS question: did you "Inspect" both types in your browser to see what is different?

Comment: Yes but I can't quite work it out and sorry about the php tag, I did that as the whole thing is being saved as a php file

Answer (score 0):

You needed to add a width to the button because it was in the div container as the others weren't.  Below i changes width to 100% instead of 15%, and added padding left and right according to the other button sizes. Hope it Helps.

```
    /** Button Styles **/
   .dropdown button {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-left:60px;
    padding-right:60px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that that was happening